# What is the request code in Android recognition API

Tags: java, android, voice

```
            Intent recIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            recIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            recIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.ENGLISH);
            recIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Need to speak");
            try {
                startActivityForResult(intentRec, REQ_CODE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Opps! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(resultCode) {
        case REQ_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(data.hasExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

I have been following the tutorials for recognition API and I still didn't get what is the request code and why the code isn't working anymore, it doesn't show any errors or even respond to my action with false
so how can I use request code? the code doesn't show any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do initial setup for speech to text and whenever you try to speak at that time you need to call speak method.
Follow below code :

```
    private var mTextToSpeechListener: TextToSpeech? = null
    val REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 5003

 /**
 * Showing google speech input dialog
 */
private fun speechToTextOutput() {
    val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
    intent.putExtra(
        RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM
    )
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say something")
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT)
    } catch (exp: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Lg.d(TAG, "speechToTextOutput: $exp")
    }

}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT -> {
                val resultSpeech = data!!
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)
                if (resultSpeech != null && resultSpeech.size > 0) {
                    mBinding.txtSpeechToText.text = resultSpeech.get(0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```